# Graph Partition

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Consider a graph 'g':

```
g = KaryTree[50, 3, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"];
g1 = FindGraphPartition[g, 2]
g2 = HighlightGraph[g, Map[IGWeightedSubgraph[g, #] &, g1]]
```

[image]

Why doesn't the 'FindGraphPartition' command split the 'g' graph into two independent and coherent (connected) graphs? You can see that e.g. two red graphs are not connected.
How to split a graph (especially weighted) into two approximately equal parts in the middle of the graph? (e.g. on the `GraphCenter[g][[1]]` node)

Comment: I believe `FindGraphPartitions` uses [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview). See the METIS FAQ [Why am I getting non-contiguous partitions?](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/faq?q=metis/metis/faq#contigous). Perhaps you can petition Wolfram Research to expose the option that forces partitions to be contiguous.